# Don't know what means $(x,y) \in N\times N$ in this task

Tags: logic

I need to find $A \cap B$:

$A=\{(x,y)\in N\times N ∧ 3x+3y=7\}$

$B = \{(x,y) \in N\times N ∧ 3y-3=x\}$

I have a problem because I don't know what $(x, y)\in N\times N$ means in this task. Do I need to solve the system:

```
$3x+3y=7$
$2y-3=x$
```

to get $x$ and $y$ or what?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!  If you feel that an answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark icon located on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to write this is
$$A=\{(x,y)∈\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: 3x+3y=7\}$$
$$B=\{(x,y)∈\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: 3y-3=x\}$$
$$A\cap B=\{(x,y)∈\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: 3x+3y=7\land 3y-3=x\}$$
Basically this means elements in thoses sets are in $\mathbb{N}^2$, also they need to sattisfy the equation, and therefore you are right, all we need is just solve $$3x+3y=7,2y-3=x$$ then we know which $(x,y)$ are in $A\cap B$.

Comment: Is there just one solution (5/9, 16/9)?

Comment: @zastacka2345 Yes, since this is the only solution (intersection of two lines) for $3x+3y=7$ and $2y-3=x$, so $A\cap B=\{(\frac{5}{9},\frac{16}{9})\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.